# OSGI - Find Bundle Reference By Service ID

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I am using a reference listener, with Service,Dictionary parameters in my Listener Method.

The Dictionary has a service.id, then I need to have the Bundle of that Service.

My question is, having the Service, and the Service ID, how to I get the Bundle Object.

Example:

```
<reference-listener
            bind-method="bindFormProcessor"
            unbind-method="unbindFormProcessor"
            ref="mainSvc"
            >

    </reference-listener>
```

My Java Method

```
public void bindFormProcessor(IFormProcessor formProcessor,Dictionary dictionary) {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = OsgiUtil.getBundleByObject(dictionary.get("service.id"));
        logger.info("************************ GOOOAAL " + bundle.getSymbolicName());
        //Now, I have the bundle of my Service
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define [ServiceReference](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceReference.html) as the parameter of the bind method. By using that, you can get the bundle that offers the service.

If you do not want to define ServiceReference as the parameter type (for whatever reason), you can get it with the following code:

```
ServiceReference serviceRef = bundleContext.getServiceReferences(IFormProcessor.class, "(service.id=" + serviceId + ")");
```

Comment: Thanks Balazs, I do not knowed the filter parameter, I wanted use the ServiceReference Param.. But I have a problem Cast Exception, when I retrieve the service with that ServiceReference. Thanks A lot